# Unable to launch any browser using selenium webdriver 3.0

Tags: java, selenium

When I tried to open chrome browser using *Selenium Web Driver* I am getting an error stating `Invalid Escape Sequence`.

Any ideas about the cause why this happens?

Comment: What are your steps? What have you tried? Show code. Where are you stuck? Provide HTML DOM.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\sravanthi\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
 Thread.sleep(5000);

Comment: @mriyalasravanthi as a good programming practice you should avoid using Thread.sleep()

Answer (score 0):

Surely not related to WebDriver or selenium. In system.setProp, you're providing the URL as "D:\sravanthi\". These are escape sequences. Use "`D:/sravanthi/`" or "`D:\\sravanthi\\` - double back slash"

Use a stronger IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ. You would not face the error.